# What does the ":" means in class constructors in dart?

Tags: class, oop, syntax, constructor, dart

I was reading dartlang.org resource on classes and they note the following construction:

```
import 'dart:math';

class Point {
  final num x;
  final num y;
  final num distanceFromOrigin;

Point(x, y)
  : x = x,
    y = y,
    distanceFromOrigin = sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2));
}
```

What I don't quite understand is the ":" in the Point Constructor and why/when should I use it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It starts the "initializer list".

If you have final fields like the ones in your `Point` class, then there are different ways to initialize them.

```
class Point {
  final num x = 3;
  ...
}

class Point {
  final num x;
  constructor(this.x);
}

class Point {
  final num x;
  constructor(num x) : this.x = x * 3;
}
```

This wouldn't work

```
class Point {
  final num x = 3;
  constructor(num x) {
    this.x = x * 3;
  }
}
```

because final fields can't be modified from within the constructor.

The initializer list a way to work around this limitation while still conforming to guarantees about object initialization order. It is executed before the constructor body.
It is a way to check or modify (assign default values) passed parameters before they are assigned to final fields and also do some calculations.

Using `this` in the initializer list is only allowed to assign to properties, but not to read from them to prevent access to not-yet-initialized properties.

The call to the super constructor also is done in the initializer list and should usually be the last call in the list.

```
class MyPoint extends Point {
  constructor(num x) : super(x);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you recommend Dart resources other than their online api and dartlang.org ?

Comment: I don't know. I learned most stuff from discussions in the community. Slack, (now also Gitter) Google groups, StackOverflow, GitHub issues